# AES MixColumn Polynomial Transformation

Tags: aes, rijndael

I just read about the AES MixColumn step, which can be calculated as:

$$b(x)=c(x)a(x) \pmod{X^4 +1}$$

$a(x)$ is the column to encode and $c(x)=3x^3+x^2+x+2$

My question is: how did they calculate $c(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

- Each column of 4x4 byte array S is regarded as column vector over the Rijndael field F.
  It is then updated by multiplying the column vector by a specified 4x4 matrix over F.
  Thus muxColumns modifies the state array by hte matrix multiplication (0<=j<=3),
- Hence, in your example you are encoding ${S_{(3,3)}}$ which is last row of Matrix and represented as polynomial ${3x^3+x^2+x+2}$

[image]

Comment: Ok but how (or why) are these those coefficient 2,1,1,3 ) it's the way c(x) has been determined such as b(x)=c(x)a(x) that i'm looking for

Comment: yes, MixColumns are performed in this way in AES with above matrix. So, MixColumns modifies the four column of array independently. Each column of 4x4 array is mixes by the method shown above. if your first column is [c0,c1,c2,c3], then new value of c3 is ${3 \cdot c0 + 1 \cdot c1 + 1 \cdot c2 + 2 \cdot c3}$, it is just a polynomial multiplication ,but done over finite field.  In short b(x) is the new Column  is generated by polynomial multiplication and reduced to ${mod(x^4+1)}$